# Printing chatter names from server file in a textfield Java

Tags: java

I would like to ask about how can I print the names of the chatters in a textfield that I created in my client file. Here is the code snippet of the server file that I have:

```
while (true) {
                out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                name = in.readLine();

                if (name == null) {
                    return;
                }
                synchronized (names) {
                    if (!names.contains(name)) {
                        names.add(name);

                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This piece of code gets the names of the chatters but I cannot display them in a textfield. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What type of "textfield"? AWT TextField? Swing JTextField? Android? Something else? Consider posting the details of your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's a JTextArea. I have separate server and client (java) files.

Comment: Please edit your question then. Clarity in communication is paramount when asking questions here. Please also tell us the details as to why your attempts to do this fail.

Comment: Make sure you not running the above code in the EDT and that you update the UI from only in the EDT

Answer (score 1):

You can try `jTextArea.append("ChatterName\n")` or `jTextArea.append("ChatterName<br/>")`, (I think the break tag might be the issue).

But a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) IMO would be much nicer.

```
 private DefaultListModel defaultListModel = new DefaultListModel() ;
 private JList jList = new JList(defaultListModel) ; 
 defaultListModel.addElement(chatterName);
```

That appends a chatter name nicely to a JList.